# Trying to use functions in a header/cpp file

Tags: c++

I have two files:

hello.h and hello.cpp

hello.h

```
#ifndef __HELLO_H__
#define __HELLO_H__

using namespace std;

void PrintMessage();

#endif
```

hello.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "hello.h"

using namespace std;

void PrintMessage()
{
     cout << "I want to be displayed!";
}
```

Now, I want to use `PrintMessage()` in a new .cpp file, but I keep getting an error message.  This is what I'm doing:

printingmessage.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "hello.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     PrintMessage();
     return 0;
}
```

Am I just doing something blatantly wrong?  I do have all of them in the same folder; I assume it has something to do with Dev-C++ (what I'm using to write/compile/run), but I can't figure it out.  Anyone have any ideas?

---

I created a folder on my desktop, put all three files inside, and I tried to compile my `printingmessage.cpp` file exactly as it is. This is the error I'm getting:

```
[Linker error] Undefined reference to 'PrintMessage()'
```

Comment: All identifiers with adjacent underscores are [reserved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for the implementation. Keep that in mind when using header guards (or any other names, but those are the most common violation). Even changing them to one underscore still violates another rule (starting with _<capital>), so be sure to keep that in mind as well. Also, `using namespace std;` is something you definitely **do not** want in the global space of your header files. It can cause chaos for whoever includes it.

Comment: As for the error, is it a linker error (*undefined reference to PrintMessage*)? If so, your `hello.cpp` needs to be built into your executable as well.

Comment: I should have stated that I have no control over the .h and .cpp files.  I can also only do #include "hello.h" in my main file.

Comment: You're not telling us why you think you're doing something blatantly wrong.  Are you observing something blatantly wrong?  Does it compile?  Does it link?  Does it run?

Comment: Do you know how to *link* when using Dev-C++?

Comment: Did you put all three files into a project together? Typically IDEs will link them correctly for you if you do, but not if you don't.

Comment: Food for the wolf: where do you think PrintMessage() is being compiled  to ? Perhaps an object code file (.o or .obj) ? Maybe link that into your output and it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know dev C++ , but i would strongly advise if you do any serious coding to learn/move to the terminal and use make files, or a newer IDE such as visual studios.

heres a short script you can run save it as bash.sh
something like this

```
g++ hello.cpp -O2 -g -c 
g++ hello.o printmessage.cpp -Wall -O2 -o print
```

then run it with ./print

Comment: Yes, you have the bliss of not having it be the thing given to you by the class environment, but you don't have to make projects in Dev - you  can compile and run just one file. While a time and space saver for things that aren't actual projects, you have to link them yourself if such linking is required.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume it has something to do with Dev-C++ (what I'm using to
>   write/compile/run), but I can't figure it out.

I guess so, too. Behind the scenes, the following things have to happen:

1. Both files get *compiled*. This creates a `*.obj` file for every `*.cpp` file, and uses the header.
2. The object files are *linked* against one another and possibly against required libraries.

Your problem lies in the “one another” part of the second step: the code *compiles* all right, but linking fails. The header file is irrelevant at that point. More precisely, the linker invocation for `printingmessage.obj` contains a reference to a function which isn't defined in that object file or any of the default libraries. Most likely the problem is due to the `*.cpp` files not being part of the same project. You need to create a multi-source-file project where you can link multiple object files. How you do that with Dev-C++ is probably somewhere in their manuals.